# PHP - is there any way to get client user name (AD)

Tags: php, linux, apache, authentication, web

I am developing a web based tool and planning for a role based access to the tool. Currently all the users who use  this tool will access the tool web portal from their laptop after authenticating to it using active directory authentication.

My server side configuration is based on Apache webserver and PHP on an RHEL machine.

So is there any way to get the AD user ID of the user using which he logged into his laptop, so that I can allow him to access only those pages allowed for him.

Comment: i would bet not. And even if it was possible, securing Access only over an ID which the OS gives to the Browser isn't very secure. Futhermore what do you do if somebody want to Access your tool on Mac/Linux ?

However you can Access the LDAP with php, so the user can Login the Webtool with the same credentials as on his laptop

Comment: Hi Doktor OSwaldo, I looked at that option, but due to some restrictions, I wont be able to use SSO for this tool. Managing authentication within the tool also not feasible due to difficulty in maintaining it. is there any other solution do you see which will meet my requirement?

Comment: And this tool doesnt contain any critical non-sharable information, only thing I want is to display only those data that is related to that user.

Comment: surely the users log onto their laptops with a domain account so can you not use the standard ldap functions available within PHP?

Comment: @RamRaider can u provide some more details? i was searching for it but couldnt find any.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
$userName= gethostname();
```